# With respect to the concept of Advaita, why is there separate Karma for different people?

Tags: karma, advaita, consciousness

According to the concept of *Advaita*, we say that 'Turiya', the supreme observer illuminates all the 3 forms the waker, dreamer, and deep sleep form of a human being. And also that every living being is united by Turiya. Then why is there separate karma for everyone if at the core we all are originating from a single entity?

Comment: From the turiya state there is no karma. Karma is only found within Maya.

Comment: Its not Karma, its a process of evolution and devolution for every being. Just like in a multiplayer game, several players are playing parallely at different levels and scores, based on their past performance but with the same predefined ambiance without having any idea of the programming of game, similarly Maya or world is the projection of universal consciousness in which several beings are existing in different forms, without knowing how they ended up in that family or that form with that genes and ambiance. Brain behind Maya and processing of everyone's Karma is the Atman in Turiya state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lack of understanding of Turiya. Turiya is not an observer.

**Turiya**

> Thou liest in the Cosmic Waters in the state of Turiya, which is
> neither absorption in the oblivion of deep sleep, nor involvement in
> the objective movement of the waking and dream states.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana** VII.9.30

Turiya is a state beyond deep sleep, dream and waking state. It does not unite all  living beings. You are really asking if all of us are Brahman according to Advaita Vedanta then why there is separate karma for everyone.

The answer is that karma only operates at the level of the physical and subtle body of everyone and not at the level of Brahman. There is different karma for every one since the physical and the subtle bodies are different for everyone.